# Linux Firewall - Complex Scenario

Tags: linux, firewall, pfsense

Ok, heres the situation I'm trying to resolve.

We've got two ISPs each providing a block of 5 static addresses.

Right now we've got a pair of Cisco 2610 routers managing them.
Things were mostly running fine, then we added additional bandwidth that the 2610 cant handle.

I'd like to replace them both with a single system running PFSense to give us a single management point as well as some flexibility.

I'm providing various services distributed across both connections, Email, Web, VPS, etc.

I'm attempting to do this with what I've got on hand and if things work out well budget in new hardware down the road.

Server: [Compaq Proliant ML310](http://tinyurl.com/abcxx)

Nics:(3) [Intel Pro/1000 MT](http://www.intel.com/network/connectivity/products/pro1000mt_server_adapter.htm)

Right now I've got it up and running and doing some basic port forwards and managing some of my non-critical services, on only one of the connections, and things seem to be working fine. What I need to do going forward is where I'm running into problems. I want to start migrating some of the VPS over to it.

Right now I think I can see several ways of doing it, I'm just looking for some tested methods to help me minimize my downtime while I test/migrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is not a supported config with pfsense. We've resolved to just running multiple pfsense front ends, 1 for each ISP and having a third in place for backup in the event of a hardware failure.